# Delete Duplicates Using ROW_NUMBER() Ordered Over Key on Joined Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble figuring out how to delete duplicate records from my Records table. I'd like to keep the oldest file and delete all newer ones. The date of creation is stored in another table, ImportHistory.

Currently I have:

```
DELETE x
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY rec.RecordID 
            ORDER BY imp.CompletedOn DESC
        ) AS DupNum
        , rec.*
    FROM Records AS rec
    JOIN ImportHistory AS imp ON rec.ImportID = imp.ImportID
) AS x
WHERE x.DupNum > 1;
```

However, I can't seem to use this method as 'x' is linked to multiple tables.
Changing the top line to "DELETE rec" doesn't work as 'rec' isn't defined in that context.

I've also considered taking the records I wish to save, pushing that into a temporary table, and then deleting all records that have duplicates before re-pushing the kept records back onto the main table, but I'm running into problems there as well.

I know adding the 'CompletedOn' column directly to records would solve the issue, but I'm trying to avoid editing any table structure.

------------EDIT---------------
We ran into a few other problems with the base data and decided to generate our own primary keys, which did require altering the base table in the end. A pain, but with the issues we found it was necessary. That made deletion much easier. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Do you need a `JOIN`? Wouldn't an `EXISTS` be a better choice?

Comment: Strange, your method usually works for me, do you get error about multiple tables or what happens

Comment: @siggemannen Correct, I get 'View or function 'x' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.' to be specific

Comment: @ThomA I specifically need the 'CompletedOn' value from ImportHistory matched to all records in Records via 'ImportID' to properly order the records

Comment: We need sample data and desired results in order to correctly answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Just join your calculation to the actual table e.g.

```
DELETE r
FROM Records r
JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY rec.RecordID 
            ORDER BY hist.CompletedOn DESC
        ) AS DupNum
        , rec.RecordID
    FROM Records AS rec
    JOIN ImportHistory AS imp ON rec.ImportID = imp.ImportID
) AS x
WHERE x.DupNum > 1 and r.RecordId = x.RecordId;
```

Comment: You can hack it with a `MERGE`, although I suspect this isn't supposed to work, and seems to have bugs, because the table being deleted depends on which table is placed first in the `FROM` rather than on any columns being selected https://dbfiddle.uk/0QizVOoF

Comment: @Charlieface you should add an answer :)

Comment: Was starting to write one, then realized the buggy behaviour. I may do so, but want to get to the bottom of this first, and gonna post on [dba.se] first.

Comment: Joining it to the actual table deletes ALL records that match the RecordId produced from the calculation, including the original as they both satisfy the condition.

Comment: @DravenTy are you saying RecordId is not unique? If that's the case please provide sample data and desired results .

Comment: @DravenTy You need to join by primary key

Comment: See my answer and linked post on the bug

Comment: @Charlieface does your answer still assume a unique PK?

Comment: No, it assumes that whatever logic OP uses already to identify those rows is correct. `RecordID` may be non-unique, one would hope that the `ORDER BY` would be deterministic though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without a self-join then you can hack `MERGE` using a dummy source table.

In practice, I'm not perfectly confident on this method. It appears to have [a serious bug](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334983/merge-delete-on-joined-tables-is-allowed-but-has-a-bug) as to which table gets modified. A workaround appears to be to add a redundant (and never used) `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause.

```sql
WITH Numbered AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY rec.RecordID 
            ORDER BY hist.CompletedOn DESC
        ) AS DupNum
        , rec.RecordID
    FROM Records AS rec
    JOIN ImportHistory AS imp ON rec.ImportID = imp.ImportID
),
Filtered AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Joined
    WHERE DupNum > 1
)
MERGE Numbered n
USING (VALUES(0)) AS v(dummy)
ON 1=0    --never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET RecordID = n.RecordID    -- extra redundant clause due to bug
    -- the column should be one of the columns in the table to be updated
;
```